# Update field A value when a field B is changed

Tags: forms, ms-access, sql-update, onchange

My form contains a registration date, 3 order event dates (different, random stages in ordering) and a numeric holding "days since last activity".

```
Customer Register: 2009-08-11
Stage A: 2011-03-12
Stage B: 2012-01-10
Stage C: 2009-09-30
Days since last activity: 882
```

I need to calculate "days since last activity", and the activity can occur in a non-sequential way across the 3 date fields.    I have a query to handle this on the entire worksheet, but I'm stuck on setting up the form to auto-update the "days since last activity" field any time a date is changed/entered.

Is there a efficient way of triggering an update query on a single row of data, when one of these 3 date fields changes?

Comment: Is "days since last activity" both a text box on the form and a field in the table?

Answer (score 0):

If Stage A, Stage B and Stage C are textboxes on your form, you can use the AfterUpdate event on each of them to recalculate the DaysSinceLastActivity:

```
Private Sub StageA_AfterUpdate()

   'Run your query here

End Sub
```